# Rebuild MFC with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to rebuild MFC with Visual Studio 2015 Professional? If so, how? (I know this used to be possible.) I need a version of the MFC static libraries that's built with the flag `/Zc:threadSafeInit-` to work with a legacy application that's infeasible to update for thread-safe static variables.

Comment: That's a good question. Unfortunately, I don't know the answer. To increase your chances, you might want to outline, how you did this in the past, and how it is failing for you with Visual Studio 2015. You might also want to investigate the legal issues involved.

Comment: You used to build them with a command like `nmake /f atlmfc.mak MFC LIBNAME=MFC70 `. Microsoft allows this, there are no legal issues, as described in the first section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235264(v=vs.110).aspx. This question was previously asked on stackoverflow with no answers regarding Visual Studio 2010 in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927672/how-to-build-mfc-library-from-source-with-visual-studio-2010.

Comment: @IInspectable FYI with MSVC 4 to 6 rebuilding MFC was easy because MS provided the make file. Since they have switch to MSBuild, they didn't provide the .sln/.vcproc files anymore.